# Can't load Mono.CSharp.dll in either Unity3D or a C# project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, evaluation

I'm working on an online video game project using Unity3D for the clients, and C# servers.
I'm trying to use some code eval for a specific feature, but I can't get it to work.

I went with Mono, because it seemed to be one of the lightest and one of the simplest. I installed Mono and got the "Mono.CSharp.dll" for .Net 4.6 from "Mono\lib\mono\4.6-api". (Both Unity and my servers are configured to use this version of .Net). I dropped it in the Unity assets, and referenced it on my servers.

But I have errors on both Unity and the servers. In Unity there is :

```
Loading script assembly "Assets/Scripts/Common/References/Mono.CSharp.dll" failed!
```

And there is an exception on the servers (my IDE is in French so I can't really copy/paste it), but it basically tells me it can't use Reference Assemblies for build, but only for reflection.

To describe the feature I want to create (because you'll maybe have a better solution), I want to be able to create spells from an external tool. Spells are made of SpellEffects. Let's say there is a SpellEffect called DealDamage, constructor takes an int (for the damage amount). I want to be able to write "DealDamage(50)" on my external tool, then take the string, and build a new DealDamage(50) from it.

I know I could find a way to interpret some code by myself, but it would be a lot more work for a far less flexible system.

It was really hard to find any help online for this problem, so as a last hope I'm turning to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you're trying to import Mono into Unity. It's already included in the installation package. If you want to make a modular spell builder, just create a regular application with your preferred language, in your preferred IDE, and save all of your spells as a JSON or XML file, and then import those into Unity. On the Unity side, just build a class to parse the files.

To get you started, take a look at the JSON.Net library. You can serialize your files into C# classes with it.

Comment: I don't think the code evaluator is already included, or maybe I missed something ?

We already chose to use protobuf for game data, but i didn't know it was possible to read JSON into C# classes, it's interesting !

Comment: What do you mean by code evaluator? Mono.Csharp.dll is the main Csharp assembly of Mono, which is included with Unity. When you say "code evaluator" I think of something like Resharper.

Comment: I mean ... I don't know, Unity doesn't find the reference when I do "using Mono.CSharp;", and I can't use Mono's evaluator either. When I say this, I mean the functionnality that lets us run some code stored in a string.

Comment: The reference to Mono is buried deep in the core engine itself. But regardless, you're doing this the hard way. You don't need to run code from a string, you just need to read and parse values and run your logic through the engine. Structure your spell building application to write JSON or XML files and import them into Unity. Once they're in there, you can deserialize back into a class and run your logic on that. Trying to parse stringified code back into compileable code is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It seems that code evaluation wouldn't work on some platforms, so I can't use it anyway. Thanks for your help and your time, I'll try to learn about JSON and XML unserialization into classes.